# How to activate control tinting on EditBox using new android support library v7

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

It seems that there is no way to activate color tinting on standard controls (EditBox and CheckBox) on KitKat with new android support v7 library (appcompact). I have tried everything.

I have followed instructions from offical android blog post to the letter:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

And I got everything working in short time without problems, except color tinting for EditBox and CheckBox.

I am not using some custom edit control (only standard android widgets), and I'm inflating all my layouts using LayoutInflater in fragments. I can only see effects of tinting with new 'SwitchCompat' widget. Oh, just to mention that I've set colorAccent in my theme.

Any ideas, what can I do to make it happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long struggle :) I got it to work !
Here is how:
All of your Activities must extend from ActionBarActivity, not from FragmentActivity, regardless if you are using actionbar or not, this is a must for tinting in support library.
Second, if you are using adapter for listview LayoutInflater for adapter must be created using themed activity as context, and for that matter any LayoutInflater that you are using must be provided by properly themed activity.

Comment: To add to this, when creating your Adapter, pass in 'this' (the activity) so that the inflater gets created off that context. It wont work if you pass in 'getBaseContext()'